# Don't see any data in UICollection view cell

Tags: swift, xcode, collections, view, collectionview

.[image]

It should be hourly weather in collectionView that under temperature label. Datasource and delegate to ViewController are done. No any errors and no any code about cell information in terminal when code run to simulator. I will be pleased for any help.

```
import UIKit

class HourlyWeatherViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {


@IBOutlet weak var hourLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var weatherOnHourLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var tempOnHourLabel: UILabel!

}
```

ViewController.swift I get information by darkskyapi.

```
import UIKit
import CoreLocation

class ViewController: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate, UITableViewDataSource,     UITableViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var hourlyWeatherCollectionView: UICollectionView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    requestLocationPermission()
    hourlyWeatherCollectionView.dataSource = self
    hourlyWeatherCollectionView.delegate = self
    self.hourlyWeatherCollectionView.reloadData()
}
func currentWeatherRequest() {
    let session = URLSession.shared
    let weatherURL = URL(string: "https://api.darksky.net/forecast/key/\(lat),\(lon)?lang=ru&unit=si" )!
    print(weatherURL)
    let dataTask = session.dataTask(with: weatherURL) { (data: Data?,response: URLResponse?,error: Error?) in
        if let error = error {
            print("Error:\n\(error)")

        } else {
            if let jsonData = data {

                do {
                    let dataString = String(data: jsonData, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)
          print("\(dataString!)")
                let decoder = JSONDecoder()
                    self.responseModel = try decoder.decode(WeatherForecast.self, from: jsonData)

                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        self.cityNowNameLabel.text = self.responseModel?.timezone
                        self.weatherNowLabel.text =  (self.responseModel?.currently.summary).map { $0.rawValue }
                        self.weatherNowdescriptionLabel.text = (self.responseModel?.currently.icon).map { $0.rawValue }
                        self.weatherFiveDaysTableView.reloadData()
                        self.hourlyWeatherCollectionView.reloadData()
                        self.reloadView()

                    }

                } catch let error {
                  print("Error: \(error)")
                }
            }else {
            print("Error: did not receive data")

        }
        }
    }
    dataTask.resume()

}
public func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
    1
}
public func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
       return responseModel?.hourly.data[0...24].count ?? 25
   }
public func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
       guard let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "HourlyWeather", for: indexPath) as? HourlyWeatherViewCell else {return UICollectionViewCell()}

       let dateList = responseModel?.hourly
       if let nowDate = dateList?.data[indexPath.row].time{
           let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
           let date = Date(timeIntervalSince1970: (TimeInterval(nowDate)))
           dateFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US")
           dateFormatter.setLocalizedDateFormatFromTemplate("HH")
           if indexPath.row == 0 {
            cell.hourLabel.text = "Now"
           }
           cell.hourLabel.text = dateFormatter.string(from: date)
           print(dateFormatter.string(from: date))
       } else {
           cell.hourLabel.text = "No data"
       }

       cell.weatherOnHourLabel.text = String(describing: dateList?.icon)
       print(String(describing: dateList?.icon))
       cell.tempOnHourLabel.text = String(describing: dateList?.data[indexPath.row].temperature)
       print(String(describing: dateList?.data[indexPath.row].temperature))
           return cell
   }
```

Comment: does it print `dataString`?

Comment: No. It don't print anything

Comment: Looks like data is empty then, check your request URL

Comment: @Scriptable URL request is right you can check https://api.darksky.net/forecast/1dcbd502506839effc15e04a5ecb687f/37.785834,-122.406417?unit=si

Comment: in the code you have posted i dont see currentWeatherRequest being called?

Comment: @Scriptable yes it was

Comment: @Scriptable now getting error to terminal ataCorrupted(Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [CodingKeys(stringValue: "currently", intValue: nil), CodingKeys(stringValue: "summary", intValue: nil)], debugDescription: "Cannot initialize Summary from invalid String value Возможен Незначительный Дождь", underlyingError: nil))

Comment: Looks like you are modelling the summery wrong, maybe it should just be a string